# Truncation problem with Xamarin.Forms iOS inline UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uidatepicker

The default iOS behaviour of a Xamarin.Forms DatePicker view is the iOS "Wheel" UIDatePicker.
[image]

Btw this control is quite ugly and users complained because they wanted (as happening in Android) a calendar view to choose from.

So after a quick search, I came across a new functionality available from iOS 14 which allows to use a "calendar" style for the UIDatePicker.

This is accomplished by a custom renderer calling the **PreferredDatePickerStyle** with the **Inline** value:

```
public class CustomDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(14, 0))
            {
                UIDatePicker picker = (UIDatePicker)Control.InputView;
                picker.PreferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.Inline;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is fine on wider iPhones, but on iPhone 8 the effect is this:

[image]

The last calendar row is off screen and there's no way to show it (no scrolling)
Has anyone encountered and solved this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue. Not only for iPhone8 but also for 8 Plus, iPhone SE. All of these devices have physical Home Button. You could report an issue here: [Xamarin.Forms Issues On Github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues). As an alternative, you could try using
UIDatePickerStyle.Compact or Automatic.

Comment: I ended up using Compact style but, honestly, it makes no sense to click twice to open the calendar.....

Comment: I just filed this issue as suggested by you
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15661

Comment: I have also commented on the link. If you've found a solution, you could share your answer here that might help people with same issues.

Answer (score 0):

UIDatePicker picker = (UIDatePicker)Control.InputView;

```
  picker.PreferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.Inline;
```

// this Line Will Fix it

```
  picker.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.None;
```